# tabindex not working same in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, tabindex

Works perfect in firefox but has issue in chrome and safari

Issue in chrome and safari is when `TAB` key is pressed `link 1` is focused (As expected). But when `TAB` is pressed second time nothing happens. Ideally focus should move to `dropdown 1`. It work when tab is press second time.

Expected to have same behaviour as firefox.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul > li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.menu ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul > li.open > ul,
.menu ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li tabindex="0" ><span>dropdown 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Link dropdown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions for your problem is to add negative tab index (`tabindex="-1"`) to links inside your `<li>`.

For more details on `tabindex` you may read this.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/focus/using-tabindex

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul > li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.menu ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
.menu ul > li.open > ul,
.menu ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="0"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li tabindex="0" ><span>dropdown 1</span>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li tabindex="0"><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    <li tabindex="0"><a href="#">Link dropdown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```